# How to remove an element without deleting element's index?

Tags: python, indexing, element

I'm trying to find "3 biggest very first numbers" with their index in list.

I have a List with numbers `0` to `10`.

```
numbers=[3,5,2,3,3,5,6,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

With this numbers:

> Number 2  is show up: 5 Times
>
> Number 3  is show up: 4 Times
>
> Number 4  is show up: 3 Times

I have a List with calculation of percentage of numbers

```
numbersInPercentage=[(100/len(numbers))*(numbers).count(0),
(100/len(numbers))*(numbers).count(1),
...
(100/len(numbers))*(numbers).count(10)]
```

My algorithm (Code block) for finding 3 biggest numbers

```
           #first biggest
        largest_integer = max(numbersInPercentage) 
        index = numbersInPercentage.index(max(numbersInPercentage))
        print('Number is :', index," by ",largest_integer,"%")
        numbersInPercentage.remove(largest_integer) # this part killing me

           #second biggest
        second_largest_integer = max(numbersInPercentage)  
        index = numbersInPercentage.index(max(numbersInPercentage))
        print('Number is :', index," by ",second_largest_integer,"%")
        numbersInPercentage.remove(second_largest_integer) # this part killing me

           #thirdbiggest
        third_largest_integer = max(numbersInPercentage)  
        index = numbersInPercentage.index(max(numbersInPercentage))
        print('Number is :', index," by ",third_largest_integer,"%")
        numbersInPercentage.remove(third_largest_integer) # this part killing me
```

Output looks like:

> Number is : 2  by  25.0 %
>
> Number is : 2  by  20.0 %
>
> Number is : 2  by  15.0 %

This part of code deleting that index, so my current index decrease one by one.

```
numbersInPercentage.remove(largest_integer)
```

It should be looks like:

> Number is : 2  by  25.0 %
>
> Number is : 3  by  20.0 %
>
> Number is : 4  by  15.0 %

My code find biggest number with their current index very well except removing index methode killing me.

I need to assign something else that removed index or I have to remove without value of index.

Answer (score 0):

For the first 3 biggest number with their index, you could do something like:

```
numbers=[3,5,2,3,3,5,6,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

res = [(el, numbers.index(el)) for el in sorted(list(set(numbers)), reverse=True)[:3]]
```

which outputs:

```
(7, 14), (6, 6), (5, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sorted(Counter(numbers).items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:3]
[(3, 4), (5, 3), (2, 3)]
  ^  ^
  |  |
number
     |
   count
```

This returns the number alongside its count. If you want percentages then you can do the conversion later on.